# Issue with initial rendering of *ngFor with Http response data

Tags: angular

I've been working on this issue all day today and cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.  I'm sure its something simple that I'm overlooking, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

So here's the question.  I have a simple component that should render a list of application ids using *ngFor.  This list is retrieved from a web api. The http request is working as expected, I see the correct response on the network.

When the results are returned, I assign the array to a local variable in the component, and I would assume that *ngFor would recognize the change and paint the screen appropriately.

I see no client side errors listed in the browser console.  Also this is Angular 2 RC5.

application-list.component.html

```html
<h3>Applications</h3>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let app of applications">{{ app.id }}</li>
</ul>
```

app-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Application } from './application';
import { ApplicationService } from './application.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'sng-application-list',
    template: require('./application-list.component.html'),
    providers: [ ApplicationService ]
})
export class ApplicationListComponent {
    errorMessage: string;
    applications: Application[] = [];

    constructor(private applicationService: ApplicationService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getApplications();
    }

    getApplications() {
        this.applicationService.getApplications()
            .subscribe(
                applications => {
                    this.applications = applications
                },
                error => {
                    this.errorMessage = <any>error;
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: No errors in the browser? I see you're not importing Application but you have defined:     applications: Application[] = [];

Comment: That was copy paste error.

Comment: `{{ app?.id }}` try this. inside *ngFor try `{{applications|json}}` and tell me are you getting any data?

Comment: Still nothing.  I can see the data arrive and is set in the success handler of subscribe, but its like change detection never kicks in.  The list will render, after I do a follow up action that modifies the applications array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maybe a problem of AngularZone. You should try this,

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private applicationService: ApplicationService,
            private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) { }             //<----added

 getApplications() {
        this.applicationService.getApplications()
            .subscribe(
                applications => {
                    this.applications = applications;
                    this.cdr.detectChanges();              //<-----addded
                },
                error => {
                    this.errorMessage = <any>error;
                });
 }
```

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you! Do you happen to know the reasoning behind why the ChangeDetectorRef is needed in this situation.  I feel as if I have written similar code in the past which has not required its usage.

Comment: Its actually about your service which gets data from (third party) API when some event happens out of angular framework which is not known to Angular or angular can't run its cycle for binding. OR in simple words some piece of code is running out of Angular framework.